# End of statement linebreaks

Tags: line-breaks, language-design

I'm currently experimenting with a programming language. I defined the basic syntax and wrote a pretty simple parser some months ago. Today I wanted to continue the project, but after a short time there was something about the syntax that bothered me.

**The end of statement**

When I started the Project I thought using *linebreaks* as end of statement would be nice. Just like that:

```
public fnc addPerson: Person personInstance
{
    [this.collection.add: personInstance]
    return this
}
```

Now today I think it would look and fell much better using *semicolons* which also would allow putting the entire thing in one line.

```
public fnc addPerson: Person personInstance
{
    [this.collection.add: personInstance]; return this;
}
```

I really wonder what are from an objective ( not technical) perspective the **pros** and **cons** of those?

I mean using linebreaks will force the the developer (at least a bit) to write clean code. But it makes the thing pretty inflexible.

- In what kind of problems you will probably run into (as a user of the language) using the linebreak end of statement?
- What language feature limitations will I have to accept using linebreaks or semicolons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had all this before, with assembler, RPG, Cobol, and various other tabular languages where line terminators were significant. Harder to write compilers for. We don't need to go back there.

When this was first done back then, everybody realized the need for a statement continuation indicator, so you could break statements over multiple lines. Now that Scala *et al.* have reintroduced this they've forgotten that part of it, so it becomes impossible to present long statements in an acceptable format.

Not a good idea. Whitespace is whitespace, not syntax.

Answer (score 1):

- I would expect, for most people, line breaks are easier to read
- Using line breaks would introduce readability problems for very long lines
- I don't see how one would impose any limitations over the other

Answer (score 1):

The big problem with using newline as statement separator is not that you can't write multiple statements on one line (you shouldn't do that anyway, it makes it too easy to miss an important part of code).

The problem is that it makes it hard to write one long statement over several lines. For a language where this becomes a problem, have a look at JavaScript and its automatic semicolon insertion.